# Compile With Win32- Ok But With Win64- Compiler Error E2064

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle

The following code compiles with Win32 but produces Delphi compiler error E2064 left side cannot be assigned to when compiled with Win64.

```
type
  PRGB24 = ^TRGB24;

  TRGB24 = record
    B, G, R: Byte;
  end;

  PRGBArray = ^TRGBArray;
  TRGBArray = array [Word] of TRGB24;

procedure TFormCurves.ApplyCurve(Src: TIEBitmap);
var
  iRGBArray: PRGBArray;
  SFill, X, Y: Integer;
begin
  if not AImageLoaded then
    Exit;
  iRGBArray := PRGBArray(Src.Scanline[0]);
  SFill := Integer(Src.Scanline[1]) - Integer(iRGBArray);
  for Y := 0 to Src.Height - 1 do
  begin
    for X := 0 to Src.Width - 1 do
    begin
      iRGBArray[X].R := ALUT[0, ALUT[1, iRGBArray[X].R]];
      iRGBArray[X].G := ALUT[0, ALUT[2, iRGBArray[X].G]];
      iRGBArray[X].B := ALUT[0, ALUT[3, iRGBArray[X].B]];
    end;
    Inc(Integer(iRGBArray), SFill);//compiler error E2064 left side cannot be assigned to 
  end;
end;

procedure TFormCurves.GetHist;
var
  iRGBArray: PRGBArray;
  X, Y, SFill: Integer;
  iIEBitmap: TIEBitmap;
  iRGB: TRGB24;
  R, G, B, l: Byte;
begin
  if not AImageLoaded then
    Exit;
  for Y := 0 to 3 do
  begin
    AMaxHistory[Y] := 0;
    for X := 0 to 255 do
      AHistory[Y, X] := 0;
  end;
  iIEBitmap := imgView.IEBitmap;
  iRGBArray := PRGBArray(iIEBitmap.Scanline[0]);
  SFill := Integer(iIEBitmap.Scanline[1]) - Integer(iRGBArray);
  for Y := 0 to iIEBitmap.Height - 1 do
  begin
    for X := 0 to iIEBitmap.Width - 1 do
    begin
      iRGB := iRGBArray[X];
      R := iRGB.R;
      G := iRGB.G;
      B := iRGB.B;
      l := (R + G + B) div 3;
      AHistory[0, l] := AHistory[0, l] + 1;
      AHistory[1, R] := AHistory[1, R] + 1;
      AHistory[2, G] := AHistory[2, G] + 1;
      AHistory[3, B] := AHistory[3, B] + 1;
    end;
    Inc(Integer(iRGBArray), SFill); //compiler error E2064 left side cannot be assigned to 
  end;
  for Y := 0 to 3 do
    for X := 0 to 255 do
      if AHistory[Y, X] > AMaxHistory[Y] then
        AMaxHistory[Y] := AHistory[Y, X];
end;
```

How can I eliminate the compiler error with Win64?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Win64 a pointer is 64 bits wide and an `Integer` is 32 bits wide. Such a cast requires both sides of the assignment expression to be the same size.   Hence the error.

Instead of casting to `Integer` cast to `PByte`.

```
 Inc(PByte(iRGBArray), SFill);
```

All your other `Integer` casts are wrong. You have to grasp the different size of these types. You might cast to `NativeInt` to resolve them.

Comment: That fixed the compile error, but now I get run time exception with Win64  with PRGBArray(sDst)[X] := C;  No runtime error with Win32. Any ideas?  If necessary should I post the procedure in a different question?

Comment: That code is not in the question. Do you really want my opinion on code I cannot see?

Comment: Ok.. I'll post question for my run time problem